# Jsp can't resolve a class as a type for specific class?

Tags: java, jsp, compiler-errors

It's a really wierd problem

I'm trying to create an Object with type `imLol` and I'm getting the following error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /yBillie.jsp
imLol cannot be resolved to a type
10: </head>
11: <body>
12:     <%
13:         imLol x = new imLol();
14:         List<Object[]> r = x.xgetNearCoupons();
15:         Users z = Users.getInstance();
16:         


An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /yBillie.jsp
imLol cannot be resolved to a type
10: </head>
11: <body>
12:     <%
13:         imLol x = new imLol();
14:         List<Object[]> r = x.xgetNearCoupons();
15:         Users z = Users.getInstance();
16:
```

i.e. the class `imLol`  not found

but in the same time I can use the object `Users` which in the same class. what's going on?

yBillie.jsp:

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="implementations.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        imLol x = new imLol();
        List<Object[]> r = x.xgetNearCoupons();
        Users z = Users.getInstance();

    %>
</body>
</html>
```

imLol.java:

```
package implementations;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class imLol {
    public List<Object[]> xgetNearCoupons() {
        Session s = Controller.getSessionFactroy().openSession();
        s.beginTransaction();
        String mylat = "33.207933", mylng = "35.570246";
        int R = 6371;
        SQLQuery query = s.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM Businesses WHERE CAST(business_id AS DECIMAL(10) = 1");
        List<Object[]> l = query.list();
        s.getTransaction().commit();
        return l;
    }
}
```

Eclipse diagram:

[image]

eclipse doesn't make a red line below the `imLol`, but when I change it, to `gjioarege`, for example, it does.. what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is *red exclamation mark* on the project that means it is the *problem with build path.*

You can view the problem tab by pressing <kbd>ALT + SHIFT + Q</kbd> followed by <kbd>X</kbd>.
In problem tab you will see the errors and warnings as well.

To solve the problem follow these steps

1. Right click on the project
2. Build path ----> Configure Build Path...
3. Click Libraries tab

There might be problem with **JRE** or **Web server library**

- If there is any problem you will see the red cross under that library. Just select that and remove.
- To add it back again click on button *Add Library...*
- If you removed JRE library then select *JRE System Library*, click *next*

  - Select *Workspace default JRE*
  - Click *Finish*
- If you removed Server library then select *Server Runtime*, click *next*

  - Select the *server (e.g. Apache Tomcat)*
  - Click *Finish*
- Click *OK*

---

**Do not write scriptlets in JSP**, because scriptlets shouldn't be used in JSPs for more than a decade. Learn the JSP [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info), and use servlet for the Java code.
See [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1031945)

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the class imLol is in class path? Probably missing in the deployment. Check in WEB-INF/classes or in WEB-INF/lib as a jar.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, there is a red exclamation mark on your project. I bet it is a classpath problem, then compiler fails.